# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleStopRecording' of undefined

Tags: angular, recordrtc

i am calling handleStopRecording() function but i am getting error ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleStopRecording' of undefined

```
stream.getTracks().forEach(function (track) {
      track.addEventListener(
        "ended",
        function () {
          callback();
          callback = function () {
            console.log("stop recording")
            this.handleStopRecording()
          };
        },
        false
      );
      track.addEventListener(
        "inactive",
        function () {
          callback();
          callback = function () {
            console.log("end");
          };
        },
        false
      );
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, viewer the context of **this**. Inside a function, the value of this depends on how the function is called.

You can more information in: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this